# Add a string to a collection and display it

Tags: java

I am writing a program for a user to add a string to an `ArrayList` then display it.
It doesn't work and it seems there is a problem with `compareTo()`.

Here is my code:

```
public class database {

    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static String country[] = new String[100];
    static String capital[] = new String[100];
    static double population[] = new double[100];
    static List<String> countriesList = Arrays.asList(country);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        country[0] = "Barbados";
        country[1] = "France";
        country[2] = "Nigeria";
        country[3] = "USA";
        country[4] = "Japan";
        capital[0] = "Bridgetown";
        capital[1] = "Paris";
        capital[2] = "Abuja";
        capital[3] = "Washington";
        capital[4] = "Tokyo";
        population[0] = 65.3;
        population[1] = 315.8;
        population[2] = 170.1;
        population[3] = 2840;
        population[4] = 126.7;

    public static void searchCountry() throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String output;
        int size, i;
        System.out.println("Search Country:");
        output = br.readLine();
        boolean found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++)
            if (output.compareTo(country[i]) == 0) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        if (found)
            System.out.println(output + " is found at index " + i);
        else
            System.out.println(output + "Country not found, choose Add country to add it");

    public static void listCountry() throws IOException {
        for (String c : countriesList) {
            if (!=null)
            System.out.println(c);

        }
    }
}
```

There is also a problem with the `null` at the end of my code.

Comment: What does the complier complain ?

Comment: inside main, you write another mothod. and you dont close curly brackets

Comment: if (!=null): You don't check anything for being null. Maybe you mean if(c!=null)

Comment: Inside main you write another method and inside that method you write yet another method. You're attempting recursion the wrong way. :)

Comment: need to learn?? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Guys, we should be support new users, I dont see any point of downvoting

Answer (score 1):

While writing code, you should better start from the beginning. i.e.

First, write class name and make sure it there is no problem with brackets

```
public class MyClass{
}
```

Then, write main method in it.

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Then, write your methods, and test it in main method.

```
public class MyClass{
    public void mymethod(){
        //do something
        System.out.println("say something");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
         MyClass mc = new MyClass();
         mc.mymethod();
    }
}
```

If you try to write everything in one shotm it wont work and if you are not expert it would be hard for you to solve problem.

Comment: sorry i didnt give u the first part of the program just what was giving problems   here is the full problem  thanks for your help

Comment: Thnaks for all your help i got it running properly now thanks again.  i had to change from compareTo to equalTo.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't write a method in a method. Close the brackets of `main()` before you open the brackets of `searchCountry()`
2. You don't check anything against being null. Maybe you mean `if(c != null)`

Just write it this way and you should be fine:

```
public class database {

    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static String country[] = new String[100];
    static String capital[] = new String[100];
    static double population[] = new double[100];
    static List<String> countriesList = Arrays.asList(country);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        country[0] = "Barbados";
        country[1] = "France";
        country[2] = "Nigeria";
        country[3] = "USA";
        country[4] = "Japan";
        capital[0] = "Bridgetown";
        capital[1] = "Paris";
        capital[2] = "Abuja";
        capital[3] = "Washington";
        capital[4] = "Tokyo";
        population[0] = 65.3;
        population[1] = 315.8;
        population[2] = 170.1;
        population[3] = 2840;
        population[4] = 126.7;
        searchCountry();
        listCountry();
    }

    public void searchCountry() throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String output;
        int size, i;
        System.out.println("Search Country:");
        output = br.readLine();
        boolean found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++)
            if (output.compareTo(country[i]) == 0) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        if (found)
            System.out.println(output + " is found at index " + i);
        else
            System.out.println(output + "Country not found, choose Add country to add it");
    }

    public void listCountry() {
        for (String c : countriesList) {
            if (c!=null)
                System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you youre searchCountry() and list dont compile , i didnt give whole program here it is

Comment: import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
 /**
     * Java assignment 1.
     * 
     *
     */
    public class database
    {
       static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       static String country [] = new String[1000];
       static String capital [] = new String[1000];
       static double population [] = new double[1000];

Comment: the program works now i changed from compareTO to equalTo.  thank you all for your help

Comment: you could accept the answer that helped you most to honor our effort ;)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `c` in `c != null`.
 You cannot define methods inside of methods in java. 
 Also,  use the `equals` method when testing for`String` equality, ie `if (output.equals(country [i]))`.

Comment: Thank you i did forget the c   were do i define methods inside of methods